# @aws-sdk/client-sqs is not working in lambda layer

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, aws-lambda-layers

I am trying to push a message from lambda layer to sqs using the @aws-sdk/client-sqs package, but this does'nt work and also does'nt throws any error. It is working in local and in lambda, but error occurs when trying from lambda layer.

The code in the layer is as follows :

```
const crypto = require("crypto");
const { SQSClient, SendMessageCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-sqs");
const { getContext } = require('./context');
const { messageGroupId } = require('./constants');

const pushError = async (type, error) => {
    const context = getContext();
    const attributes = {
        type: {
            DataType: "String",
            StringValue: type,
        },
        message: {
            DataType: "String",
            StringValue: error.message,
        },
        name: {
            DataType: "String",
            StringValue: error?.name
        },
        stack: {
            DataType: "String",
            StringValue: error?.stack
        },
        functionName: {
            DataType: "String",
            StringValue: context.functionName
        },
        logGroup: {
            DataType: "String",
            StringValue: context.logGroupName
        },
        logStream: {
            DataType: "String",
            StringValue: context.logStreamName
        }
    };
    const hash = crypto.createHash("sha256");
    hash.update(JSON.stringify(attributes));
    const deduplicationId = hash.digest("hex");
    const params = {
        MessageBody: error.message,
        QueueUrl: process.env.sqsUrl,
        MessageAttributes: attributes,
        MessageDeduplicationId: deduplicationId,
        MessageGroupId: messageGroupId
    }

    const sendMessageCommand = new SendMessageCommand(params);
    try {
        const sqsClient = new SQSClient({ region: process.env.region , accessKeyId: process.env.accessKey, secretAccessKey: process.env.secretKey});
        console.log("SQS Client : ", JSON.stringify(sqsClient));
        console.log('before pushing message : ',process.env.region );
        console.log('Remaining time: ', context.getRemainingTimeInMillis());
       
        const response = await sqsClient.send(sendMessageCommand);
         
        console.log("Message sent successfully. Message ID:" , response.MessageId);
        console.log('after pushing message : ', process.env.sqsUrl);
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.error("An error occurred while alerting error: ", error);
    }
}


module.exports = { pushError };
```

The console till **Remaining time:**  gets printed, but after that the lambda is getting stopped. There are lot of time remaining , the lambda is not getting timed out. I have given all the env variables used in code in lambda configuration. I have  added SQS full access to lambda + the accessKey and secretKey given also has the full access to sqs.

The calling function is as follows:

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');
const { errorConstants } = require('./constants');
const {pushError} = require('./sqs');

const eventEmitter = new EventEmitter();

const event = () => {
   return eventEmitter;
}

const events = [errorConstants.file, errorConstants.dynamo, errorConstants.rabbitMQ, errorConstants.email, errorConstants.fetch, errorConstants.scheduler, errorConstants.storage, errorConstants.event];

for (const event of events) {
   eventEmitter.on(event, async (error) => {
       try {
           console.log('before pushError function call ', event, error);
          await pushError(event, error);
          console.log('after pushError function call ', event, error);
       } catch (error) {
           console.log(`Error while pushing ${event} `, error);
       }
   });
};

module.exports = { event };
```

The sqsClient is properly getting created the same way when checked in layer and lambda

Comment: Just a quick question to rule it out, does your lambda function hve the correct execution policies?

Comment: yeah , it has , the policy is as follows


{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "sqs:*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Can you add your calling code?

Comment: @Corey , added the calling function code. i am using eventEmitter to catch on a particular event and push message to sqs.

Comment: Why are you supplying IAM user credentials to this code and why are you doing it via environment variables? Lambda functions have a much better credential mechanism via configured IAM roles.

Comment: @jarmod currently using the iam role in lambda only, still not working. The above code, I simply tried out, to test if there is error in that policy

Comment: How are you determining that it fails? Any chance you have used the wrong AWS credentials which pertain to a different AWS account?

Comment: No i am having only one credential, that points only to that account, I think the sqsclient is not properly getting created in lambda layer, attaching the screenshots in question now @jarmod

Comment: The image you attached includes access key and secret key. You should immediately deactivate/rotate these credentials.

Comment: Thankyou @jarmod, now edited

Comment: Just be sure to deactivate/rotate your credentials because the post's edit history is available to viewers.

Comment: I think you may be supplying parameters incorrectly to the v3 SDK SQS client constructor. Try: `new SQSClient({ region, credentials: { accessKeyId, secretAccessKey, sessionToken } })`.

Comment: @jarmod tried  `new SQSClient({ region, credentials: { accessKeyId, secretAccessKey, sessionToken } })` still unable to push

Comment: Ensure that you're providing credentials correctly and do that outside of Lambda first to check it's good. You said "the lambda is not getting timed out" yet neither line of trace following the call to `sqsClient.send` is being logged (at least that's what I think you are saying) so that does suggest a network connectivity issue and a timeout. Can you add the full CloudWatch Logs to your post (be sure to redact anything sensitive)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is I was emitting a event(fn1) for calling the pushError function.
Since emitting event we cannot add await, when the code hits the client.send line , it then goes back to the place where i was emitting the event(fn1) and that function is getting ended, and lambda gets terminated. Fixed this issue by emitting another event after sqs message push and catching that event inside a Promise in fn1.
Thankyou @jarmod, @Corey, and @mpmcintyre for your help.